# Why don’t English speakers say “I’m cold very much”?

Tags: sentence-usage

When I’m very cold, I noticed I say “I’m very cold.” But why not “I’m cold much” or “I’m cold very much”?

You can say “I’m cold now” adverbs can be added and “be” and “cold” mean the same. Or, "I like James much".

Comment: Why would you think that "I am cold much" is correct.  Is there a similar sentence in English or another language that has this structure with "much" at the end?

Comment: @James K Yes, but it’s not at the end.

Comment: @James K Because like “I’m cold now” adverbs can be added and “be” and “cold” mean the same. ex) I like James much.

Comment: "be" and "cold" don't mean the same, even if in other languages no copular verb is used.  I know that Korean (for example) doesn't have a verb like "be" in English to join an adjective to a subject.  English does.  That doesn't mean that "be" means "cold".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The adverb to modify the adjective "cold" is placed before the adjective, not after it.  That is just a "rule" of grammar.

The correct adverb to use is "very" and not "much".  That is the meaning of "very".

In the other examples you give, the adverb modifies the verb.  "I'm cold now", the adverb now gives the time of "being", it doesn't modify the adjective "cold".  "I like James much" is not good English,  "I like James a lot" is correct, but again the adverb "a lot" modifies "like" not "James".

Comment: “a lot” can’t modify an adjective?

Comment: No.  You say "very cold" not "a lot cold".  "I'm cold a lot" would mean "I'm cold often", and the adverb is modifying the verb.

Comment: But together in we are close together modifies close after an adjective.

Comment: "close together" is a compound, like "far apart". It functions as a single word.

Comment: But that's irrelevant since "together" is a different word from "a lot" or "very" or "much" There's no reason why a different word should have the same grammar rules.

Comment: Thank you but back to the point what does “be” mean?

Comment: used to say something about a person, thing, or state, to show a permanent or temporary quality, state, job, etc.:

Comment: "be" is a copular verb.   It joins the subject to adjective or noun.  It is a connecting word and has no translation into Korean.